# Need Xtify SDK for Worklight V6.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, xtify

We developed an Worklight Hybrid application on Worklight V6.0. Till now there is no push notification implemented for this application, client told to use Xtify push notification tool for push notification.

I'm new to Xtify and I downloaded the Xtify working POC sample from Xtify site and try to run on Worklight eclipse V6.0, but ended with errors, and I run the same Sample code on Worklight V6.2, it is working fine.

Whether Xtify supports Worklight V6.0?

Answer (score 1):

Xtify support is available start Worklight 6.1 and above. It is not available for Worklight 6.0: https://developer.ibm.com/push/docs/ibm-mobile-push-notification/ibm-worklight/

Note also that Worklight 6.0 is **very old**. Tell your client to upgrade to 6.3 or 7.0

Comment: Your client should contact Xtify then.